# JSON:API does not return relationships with pagination

Tags: search

When I use `/jsonapi/index/products?include=field_product_image`, it returns image details inside 'included' parameter in the response.

When I use `/jsonapi/index/products?include=field_product_image&page[offset]=1&page[limit]=3`, "included" data is missing from the response, so can't we have relationship data with pagination in Drupal.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no question here. If you think you found a bug: Bug reports should be posted as issue on drupal.org instead.